# Numpy array access function derivative

Tags: numpy, matrix, mathematical-optimization, tensor, derivative

I try to come up with the derivative to the following function:

```py
def f(x, item):
  return x[item]

def df_dx(x, item):
  pass
```

where item is as defined in the numpy doc can be list, slice, int, list of slice.

But there are so many edge cases but it feels like there should be a very easy multiplication between two tensors that should be kind of the answer. Can anyone help?

I tried something like this:

```py
 to_length = lambda i: i if type(i) == int else len(
            range(i.start, (i.stop if i.stop is not None else -1), (i.step if i.step is not None else 1)))

        input_shape = list(X.shape)
        seg_shape = []
        if type(self.item) == int or type(self.item) == slice:
            seg_shape = [to_length(self.item)]
        elif type(self.item) == list:
            seg_shape = [to_length(i) for i in self.item]
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Unknown type {type(self.item)}")

        v = np.zeros(seg_shape + input_shape)
        if len(seg_shape) == 1:
            # np.fill_diagonal(v[:, self.i:self.i + self.n], 1)
            np.fill_diagonal(v[..., self.item], 1)
            return v
        elif len(seg_shape) == 2:
            np.fill_diagonal(v[:, :, self.item[0], self.item[1]], 1)
            return v
```

But it didn't really work.

Comment: `x[item]` is an indexing operation.  "derivative" does not have any meaningful analog, regardless of what `item` is.  Or what `x` is.  The interpreter evaluates it as `x.__getitem__(item)`.

Comment: `np.aranage(5)[[1,3]]` is `np.array([1,3])`.  `np.arange(5)[3:]` is `np.array([3,4])`.  You can't do `np.arange(5)[[1.01, 3.01]]`. in the derivative analog of `(f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx`.

Comment: Just view item as constant. I want the derivative with respect to x.

Answer (score 0):

Your defined function isn't continuous.  There is a numpy `gradient` function.  Which may do what you want.

```
import numpy as np

x = ( np.arange( 20 ) - 10 ) * .1
x = x*x

x
#  array([1.  , 0.81, 0.64, 0.49, 0.36, 0.25, 0.16, 0.09, 0.04, 0.01, 0.  ,
#         0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.25, 0.36, 0.49, 0.64, 0.81])

def f(x, item):
    return x[item]

def df_dx(x, item):
    return np.gradient( x )[ item ]

df_dx( x, None )
# array([[-0.19, -0.18, -0.16, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1 , -0.08, -0.06, -0.04,
#         -0.02,  0.  ,  0.02,  0.04,  0.06,  0.08,  0.1 ,  0.12,  0.14,
#          0.16,  0.17]])

df_dx( x, [ 2, 8, 10, 17 ] )
# array([-0.16, -0.04,  0.  ,  0.14])
```